# expected ActionController::RoutingError but was not given a block in rails app rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I try to test my RoR application. When i test to cause ActionController::RoutingError in my controller i get following errors:
  Got 1 failure and 1 other error:

```
 2.1) Failure/Error: expect(visit meters_path).to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
        expected ActionController::RoutingError but was not given a block
      # ./spec/integration/meter_behavior_spec.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2.2) Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')

      ActionController::RoutingError:
        Not Found
```

What is the reason?
It is my list of testing gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.4'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
end
```

my spec file

> meter_behavior_spec.rb

```
  scenario 'a visitor cannot to view meters pages', driver: :webkit do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:client1)
    user.meters.create(attributes_for(:meter))          
    expect(visit meters_path).to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
  end
```

> meters_controller.rb:

```
 before_action only: :index do
    access_allowed_for(['Client'])
  end
  # GET /meters
  # GET /meters.json
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: MetersDatatable.new(view_context, current_user) }
      format.html
    end
  end
```

> application_controller.rb:

```
  def access_allowed_for(statuses_ary=[])
    statuses_ary << 'Admin'
    if !user_signed_in? || statuses_ary.exclude?(current_user.try(:status))
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue as pointed out in Jean-Christophe's answer is that the `raise_error` matcher needs a block.  The second issue is you're testing something that would really be better tested in a controller test (not Capybara driven) instead of a feature test.

If you insist on testing this in a feature test then there's a few things you need to verify

1. Make sure you don't have any gems in the test environment that are catching the errors and producing nice/detailed error pages.  This would include gems like `web_console`, `better_errors`, etc. Those gems should be only in the development environment.
2. Make sure you have set `Capybara.raise_server_errors = true` in your test config
3. You may need to add a second Capybara statement inside the block.  This is because Capybara runs the app in a separate thread from the tests and the visit call may occur asynchronously (depending on the driver you use).  That means the error may not have actually been raised when the visit call returns.  By adding a second call to a capybara method it will wait a little bit for the visit to finish and then detect that an error was raised in the server/app thread and re-raise that error in the test thread.

   ```
    expect{
      visit meters_path
      page.has_text? 'Random text' # only here to give time for app to raise error
    }.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
   ```

Comment: 1 I checked that i have both `web-console` and 'better errors` gems in my gemfile, but both in the `development` group.  2 Then i added `Capybara.raise_server_errors = true` string into `spec/support/capybara.rb` file, but got the error again. 3 Finally i added `page.has_text?` statement and it helped. Thank you.

Comment: When i comment `Capybara.raise_server_errors = true` string, test whatever works well.

Comment: @ЭрикКеубасов Yes - it defaults to true, I just wanted to make sure you hadn't reset it to false somewhere.

Comment: To my shock, this technique still solves this same problem almost 6 years later.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should simply pass visit meters_path as a block and not as an argument, like so :

```
expect{visit meters_path}.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
```

See :

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-2/docs/matchers/expect-error

Tell me if it works.

Comment: thanks, but it did not help. i corrected and get an similar error:                1.1) Failure/Error: expect{visit meters_path}.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
            expected ActionController::RoutingError but nothing was raised

     1.2) Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')

Comment: Ok, it's going in the right direction nonetheless. The first failure is now in the code you're testing, instead of your test code. Does the test pass if you automatically raise the error either in your controller action or access_allowed_for method (that is outside your conditionnal). This would rule out any issue with the raising itself. As for your conditionnal what status does your :client1 Factory give your user ? ('client' ? 'Client' ?)

Comment: When i raise error in my controller, i get similar failure/error messages. client1 has a 'Client' status. Thank you anyway.